# Why isn't counter() called in "false && counter()"?

Tags: java, boolean-expression

I am trying to figure out how this boolean expression is evaluated:

```
int i = 0;
boolean exp = i > 1 && counter();
```

In the following code:

```
public class Main {

    static int num = 0;

    public static boolean counter(){   
            num++;
         if(num == 6){
             return true;
         }
          return false;
     }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
            //int i = 2;
              int i = 0;
            boolean exp = i > 1 && counter();
            System.out.println(num); // 0
            System.out.println(exp); // false
    }   
 }
```

Since `i = 0`, `i > 1` is false and `counter()` returns false. However, I'm confused because the value of static variable `num` doesn't change despite the `counter()` function being in the boolean expression:

```
exp = i > 1 && counter();
```

I was expecting the output to be

```
1
false
```

but it is

```
0
false
```

Why does `counter()` not seem to be called?

Comment: Due to [logical short-circuiting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation), `counter()` doesn't get evaluated if `i > 1` returns `false`.

Comment: @Phylogenesis Does evaluating like this expression depends on the programming language in that case is this way of evaluating change from language to another.

Comment: @Colt As per my link, this behaviour is programming language dependent. Logical operators in Visual Basic (not VB.Net) do not short-circuit like this, for instance.

Comment: @Phylogenesis Thanks for info. very helpful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because `&&` is *short-circuiting*. When `i > 1` evaluates to false, there is no need to check the other side of the logical AND because the resulting expression will always be `false`. Therefore, the method `counter` is never run.

To fix this, you can either move `counter()` to be the first condition, or use the non-short-circuiting `&`.

Comment: Thanks alot ! that make sense.  

in this case it doesn't even execute counter function so num value still the same!

Comment: does evaluating like this expression depends on the programming language

in that case it doesn't evaluate the other side if the left side is already false

Comment: @Colt well, the expressions themselves could differ by language, but in Java and many other OOP languages, `&&` and `||` are _short-circuiting operations_ which by definition behave in that way.

Answer (score 2):

> && operator evaluates the right side expression if the left side expression is true.

If any one of the expressions is false then the entire expression would be false in the && operator case -> no need to evaluate the other expressions. So the counter() expression is not at all executed in your case.

> 0 > 1 fails..

Hence counter() is not at all evaluated.

Answer (score 0):

It's because of `&&` is quick boolean operation.
If first operand is false then it will return false immediately without evaluating second operand.
You can use `&`, it will always evaluate both operands. (also `&` is a bit-wise operator if the operands are integral.)
The same thing with logical OR : `||`. if the first operand is true, it will immediatly retrun true.